# Prevent views from being clicked until animation added to action via navigation component completes

Tags: android, android-animation, listener, android-architecture-navigation

Given 2 Fragments `A` and `B`, `A` moves to `B` (so `A -> B`), via navigation component action with enter animation has been added. How to prevent views in Fragment `B` being clickable while enter animation is running? I've found this question [How to add listener to android Navigation Architecture Component action animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55341088/how-to-add-listener-to-android-navigation-architecture-component-action-animatio[1]) but unfortunately there're no answers.

What I found in the documentation is that I could get resource ID of that animation through `NavOptions` object hooked onto the `NavAction`, but not the `Animation` object itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by having your views as disabled in xml `android:enabled="false"` then in your fragment's `onViewCreated` you can set a `delay` with the animation duration using coroutines:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedState)

    // Initialize views here. 


    lifecycleScope.launch {
        delay(resources.getInteger(R.integer.anim_duration).toLong())
        // Enable views here
        myView.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I've solved it using
coroutines and since I had a `ViewModel` behind my `Fragments` I ended up
using `viewModelScope` instead of `lifecylceScope`.

Comment: Great, yeah that also works if using a ViewModel. Its essentially the same idea but using a different class to manage the delay duration.

Answer (score 0):

While I originally solved the problem using coroutines I faced the same problem
once again :] so I investigated a bit and stumbled upon this topic [Disable clicks when fragment adding animation playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971825/disable-clicks-when-fragment-adding-animation-playing) that helped me to figure out the right solution.

Apparently those action animations added through the navigation graph are
set by `FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimation(enter, exit, popEnter, popExit)`
and these can be accessed by overriding `onCreateAnimation(transit: Int, enter: Boolean, nextAnim: Int)`. Where `nextAnim` actually represents the action animations we added. For the  fragment `A` it would be either `exit` or `popEnter` and for the fragment `B` it would be either `enter` or `popExit`.

The problem of views being clicked happens when fragment is entering (either `enter` or `popEnter`) so one can use an if statement to check `enter` and if `true` create `Animation` based on the `nextAnim` and then one can set listener to it. In case of home (starting) fragment one should exclude the case of `nextAnim = 0` since it's also entering animation.

```
override fun onCreateAnimation(transit: Int, enter: Boolean, nextAnim: Int): Animation? {
        if (nextAnim == 0 || !enter) return super.onCreateAnimation(transit, enter, nextAnim)
        else {
            return AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(requireContext(), nextAnim).apply {
                setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
                    override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
                        disableClicking()
                    }

                    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
                        enableClicking()
                    }

                    override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**: For non-home fragments to avoid disabling clicks at the start of the animation, we can start with views being unclickable in xml layout and only enable clicking when the animation ends. To remove a bug where views remain unclickable if a device rotation happens we can introduce a `boolean` variable that we will set to `true` when animation ends and preserve it by overriding `onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle)` and reinstating it in `onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)` and check if it was `true` before device rotation to re-enable clicking once again.